# Unhelpful error on RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

I am using RegisterClientScriptBlock to send a JS alert to the user when the users goes into edit mode on a gridview, but it causes my page to error for some reason and I can't figure out why...

This is the method that causes the problem. The error occurs in the last line where the script is registered. (If I comment this out the page works fine!)

```
    protected void EditRecord(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        gvStockItems.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        // Gather current Search info
        string strPartNo = Session["currentSearchTerm"].ToString();
        BindData();
        gvStockItems.SelectedIndex = gvStockItems.EditIndex;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "thisIsTest", "<script language=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"oops\");</script>");
    }
```

The error that is thrown in the JS console is

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It also says that this error occurred in Error$Create in the ScriptResource.axd, but I think this is an error that occurs on reporting what the real issue is, so I'm completely stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: My guess is it's this: `typeof(Page)`. Try changing it to `this.GetType()`

Comment: Same issue, even after changing to GetType().  :(

Comment: That's why it was a guess. :) Have you tried debugging to check that `Page` & `ClientScript` are objects? Otherwise I'm stumped as well.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help. I think the issue I'm having is that the error message and the break is not at the actual error, it's on the reporting of the error...

Comment: Is this happening within an UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yes, a grid view within an update panel.  I have found a clash with something else in web.config, which was causing that error message.  Now it doesn't error, but it also does not display the alert.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/239674/113763

Comment: Thanks will work through some of those and try to find the real problem.

Answer (score 4):

remove `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and try using `RegisterStartupScript`

```
// Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
String csname1 = "thisIsTest";
Type cstype = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
    StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('oops!') </");
    cstext1.Append("script>");

    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
}
```

OR if you have `ScriptManager` then

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "thisIsTest", "alert('oops!');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be to do with call registering scripts from code behind when doing only partial update within an update panel.  If I set `EnablePartialRendering="false"` in the script manager it all works fine.  Where as if I allow partial rendering the error occurs.

Comment: You can add the 4th parameter to RegisterStartupScript (make it True) and avoid adding messy `<script type=text/javascript>` tags yourself and concentrate just on JS code generation